# Retrieve Next Purchase Order Due and Price from that Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Purchase Order table like so:

```
+---------------+------------+---------+----------+-------+
| PurchaseOrder |  DueDate   | Product | Quantity | Price |
+---------------+------------+---------+----------+-------+
| PO1           | 04/12/2014 | A       |       20 | 19    |
| PO2           | 20/11/2014 | B       |       16 | 22    |
| PO3           | 07/11/2014 | A       |       14 | 32    |
| PO4           | 09/12/2014 | B       |        7 | 86    |
+---------------+------------+---------+----------+-------+
```

I would like a query to Sum up the Quantity for each Product, display the next Due Date, and display the Price from that Purchase Order that is next due.

The desired output would be:

```
+---------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
| Product | TotalQuantity |  NextDueDate | NextDueDatePrice |
+---------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
| A       |            34 | 07/11/2014   |               32 |
| B       |            23 | 20/11/2014   |               22 |
+---------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
```

The bit I don't know how to do (in the most efficient way) is to get the NextDueDatePrice!

I've setup an SQLFiddle which does all but that column if it helps: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/942ed/2

Many thanks in advance to any help received!!

Comment: You're going to need a subquery which gets the greatest `DurDate` for the current product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the subquery method:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/942ed/4)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE PurchaseOrders
(
  PurchaseOrder varchar(255),
  DueDate datetime,
  Product varchar(255),
  Quantity int,
  Price int,
);
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrders VALUES ('PO1','2014-12-04','A',20,19);
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrders VALUES ('PO2','2014-11-20','B',16,22);
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrders VALUES ('PO3','2014-11-07','A',14,32);
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrders VALUES ('PO4','2014-12-09','B',7,86);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  Product,
  SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity,
  MIN(DueDate) AS NextDue,
  (select Price 
   from PurchaseOrders p2 
   where p2.Product = p1.Product and p2.DueDate = MIN(p1.DueDate)) as NextPrice
FROM PurchaseOrders p1
GROUP BY Product
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/942ed/4/0)**:

```
| PRODUCT | TOTALQUANTITY |                         NEXTDUE | NEXTPRICE |
|---------|---------------|---------------------------------|-----------|
|       A |            34 | November, 07 2014 00:00:00+0000 |        32 |
|       B |            23 | November, 20 2014 00:00:00+0000 |        22 |
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TotalQuantity` you can get using basic aggregation functions but not so the `NextDueDatePrice`.  Instead, the trick is to use `row_number()` to enumerate rows and then use conditional aggregation:

```
select Product, sum(Quantity) as TotalQuantity, Max(DueDate) as NextDueDate,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then Price end) as NextDueDatePrice
from (select po.*, row_number() over (partition by Product order by DueDate) as seqnum
      from PurchaseOrders po
     ) po
group by Product;
```